# SharePoint 2010 — Visual Studio Project Structure

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, infrastructure

What are your project structures for sharepoint projects. For example my simple structure is: Think of a project named MyPortal

MyPortal.sln

--MyPortal.Branding (Custom master pages, page layouts, css-js-images that go under _kayouts)

--MyPortal.Definitions (Content types, event receivers, list definitions/instances)

--MyPortal.WebParts (webparts, user controls, custom application pages)

Comment: I will allow this Q even though it is really too broad and has many answers. Have made it CW though, as should answers be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyPortal.Controls (controls and objects)
MyPortal.Commands (logic and analytics)
MyPortal.Properties (styling)

This can be followed for just about any SharePoint project.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that you should maintain consistency and clarity when designing your project structure. You should also watch out of long solution/project/file names. I have seen people use the project namespace as the project name, later causing long path issues. I personally try to keep the file names short but descriptive enough.

Answer (score 0):

Structure for any type of SharePoint Project has differences:

1-in [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fyc0azh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can find many templates for programming:

**any type has it's own template: download them**

for example for [web parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231579%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Elements.xml
>
> Contains information that is used by the Feature definition file in
>   your project to deploy the Web Part.
>
> .webpart file
>
> Provides information that SharePoint needs to display your Web Part in
>   a Web Part gallery.
>
> Code File
>
> Contains methods that add controls to the Web Part and generate custom
>   content within the Web Part.

you can download from here:

> Visual Basic and C# SharePoint Templates

[These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fyc0azh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) templates appear under the Visual Basic/SharePoint or Visual C#/SharePoint subcategories, and may be further sorted into 2007 and 2010.

2- in [CodePlex](http://sharepointdevtools.codeplex.com/) :

> This project extends the Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Project system
>   with advanced templates and tools.

3- [SPSF](http://spsf.codeplex.com/)

> The SharePoint Software Factory is a Visual Studio Extension helping
>   SharePoint newbies, as well as experienced developers to create,
>   manage and deploy SharePoint solutions without having to know every
>   tiny XML and C# secret.

4- [cksdev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/)

> This project extends the Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint project system
>   with advanced templates and tools.